# Is it possible to make MarkdownDeep or MarkdownSharp handle mixed HTML/Markdown like Pandoc?

Tags: markdown, markdownsharp, markdowndeep

Take the following snippet of HTML mixed with Markdown.

```
<section class="section alt">
# Hello
</section>
```

[Translate online with Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try) using `Markdown (strict) -> Html` and you get this HTML:

```
<section class="section alt">
<h1 id="hello">Hello</h1>
</section>
```

Do the [same with MarkdownDeep](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/dingus) and you get this HTML:

```
<p></p><section class="section alt"><p></p>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p></p></section><p></p>
```

Notice all the crazy `<p>` tags!?  MarkdownSharp does the same.  *To be fair*, I think Pandoc is off spec here and the other two libraries are probably correct (Update: Pandoc is [intentionally off spec](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#raw-html) here (see comment from John below)).  However, the Pandoc approach is much nicer IMO.

Is it possible to make MarkdownDeep or MarkdownSharp behave like Pandoc?  If not, is there an alternative .NET markdown implementation/solution that does work like this?  (I need to include and ILMerge so can't use Pandoc).

Comment: Pandoc's deviation from the spec is documented and explained [here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#raw-html).

Comment: Thanks for the link John (and Pandoc).  You've made Pandoc too damn awesome.  Nothing else is working for me...

Comment: @JohnMacFarlane - reading the section you link to again, it seems only to concern embedding Markdown in an HTML block.  It doesn't seem to say why all the other implementations include this leading `<p></p>` when Pandoc does not.  Did I miss something?